# Multiple tables in a jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i have 2 list of custom object in my java application (List l1, List l2).
I would like to realize with jasper report a one page report that show them in 2 separate tables.

How could I solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subreports...

View this:

[Subreports](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/02/simple-guide-to-sub-reports-in-jasperreports-ireport/)

Greetings..

Comment: Provided link page is not available

Comment: @Nallamachu Try this saved version https://web.archive.org/web/20210730032131/https://www.richardnichols.net/2010/02/simple-guide-to-sub-reports-in-jasperreports-ireport/