# How can i print multiple jasper report in single page of PDF

Tags: java, multithreading, pdf, jasper-reports, report

I can print multiple reports in the single PDF file using the below code, but it's adding a new page per report.

```
JasperReport jreport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:\\FTP\\JRXML\\PatientConsultantReport\\"+checkedReport+".jrxml");
JasperPrint jprint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport1, new HashMap(), new JRResultSetDataSource(rs));
jprintlist.add(jprint1);
          .
         So ON
          .
          .
jprintlist.add(jprint5);

    JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jprintlist);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\FTP\\PDF\\VisitsSummaryReport.pdf"));
                exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
                exporter.exportReport();
```

So Question is: How can I print all data on a single page of PDF, instead of having a new page per report?

Comment: You can do it like in this sample: [Exporting Multiple Reports into a Single Output File](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport)

Comment: please go through my edit ..

Answer (score 9):

```
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();

// Create multiple jasper prints and add to a list
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
InputStream inputStream1 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("template1.jrxml");
JasperDesign jd1 = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream1);
JasperReport jr1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd1);
JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr1, params);
jasperPrintList.add(jp1);

InputStream inputStream2 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("template2.jrxml");
JasperDesign jd2 = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream2);
JasperReport jr2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd2);
JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr2, params);
jasperPrintList.add(jp2);

// Generating report using List<JasperPrint>
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
 JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

 exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, new FileOutputStream("c:/mipdf.pdf"));
 //The following is the important line
 exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, Arrays.asList(jasperPrint, jasperPrint));
 exporter.exportReport();
```

Works like charm!

Comment: thanks for reply , But should it work like multiple report are in single pdf and even in single page.

Answer (score 2):

Generate one PDF file per table and append them together using [itext](http://itextpdf.com/).

Update:

This stackoverflow post may be useful.

[Multiple tables in a jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892748/multiple-tables-in-a-jasper-report)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one. First merge your reports and export to pdf.

```
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport1, 
        parameters, dataSource1);
        List<JRPrintPage> pages = jasperPrint1.getPages();
        for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
            JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(j);
            jasperPrint.addPage(object);
        }
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream)
```

It's comman solution.